# How to check if object is of any of given types in C#

Tags: c#, .net, code-cleanup

I am working with Unity Engine where there is a base class `Component` and multiple classes deriving from it, including `Transform`, `MeshRenderer` and many classes created by me.

I want to execute an action (in this case `Destroy` all the components that aren't of types: `Transform`, `MeshRenderer`, `MeshFilter`, `Collider` and `BuildMenuItem`). My basic approach looks like this:

```
Component[] components = obj.GetComponents<Component>();
foreach (var component in components) {
    if (component is MeshFilter)
        continue;
    if (component is MeshRenderer)
        continue;
    if (component is Transform)
        continue;
    if (component is Collider)
        continue;
    if (component is BuildMenuItem)
        continue;

    Destroy(component);
}
```

In my opinion it looks ugly and the only way to shorten it I found is to use `||` operator, but it doesn't fix a lot and IMO looks even worse. Is there a cleaner way of implementing that?

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559257/how-can-i-implement-notoftypet-in-linq-that-has-a-nice-calling-syntax .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize a collection of `Type`s (e.g. `List<Type>`, `HashSet<Tepe>`, etc.), add all required types into it (`typeof(Transform)`, ...), and then use `Contains` to check whether component type is within that collection.

```
var types = new HashSet<Type> {typeof(Transform), typeof(MeshRenderer)};

Component[] components = obj.GetComponents<Component>();
foreach (var component in components.Where(c => !types.Contains(c.GetType())))
{
    Destroy(component);
}
```

---

Updated:

```
Type[] types = { typeof(Transform), typeof(MeshRenderer) };

Component[] components = obj.GetComponents<Component>();
foreach (var component in components.Where(c => !types.Any(x => c.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(x))))
{
    Destroy(component);
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't include the derived classes (eg. a `BoxCollider` which derives from `Collider` gets destroyed in your approach and not in the original)

Comment: How about modifying the lambda to `c => !types.Any(x => c.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(x))`.edit just saw the edit.

Comment: @Immorality, good point, `IsAssignableFrom` is more suitable here

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface `INotDestroyable`, make non destroyable types `Transform`, `MeshRenderer`, `MeshFilter`, `Collider` and `BuildMenuItem` implement it, and then on your loop just check if the element doesn’t implements it. The interface doesn’t have to have any properties or members defined.

Comment: It's a good idea, but for my needs it's too... "constant". I might want to have another function which filters other types and so I would need to create multiple interfaces for each of them. Although it doesn't match my needs it still has a great value

Comment: Also, a lot of the mentioned classes are Unity classes and therefore not editable.